# How to create 2 columns, 4 control with preceding labels with Bootstrap 3 keeping markup in by column order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create the following layout, which will be placed within a container `<div class='my-container'>` which can reside anywhere in the page:

```
label1:    [input1]     label3: [input3]
label2:    [x]          label4: [input4]
```

(Please note these inputs are not within a form, they are a filter facility, and client side change events are handled to react user input. I do not know is this matters or not, just providing the detailed info.)

I know I can separate my form rows using  `<div class'row'>`.

I prefer to see my html code ordered by column, (as opposed ordering by row)  because the business logic in the form is also by column. I mean:

```
<markup for label1>
<markup for input1>
<markup for label2>
<markup for input2>
<markup for label3>
<markup for input3>
<markup for label4>
<markup for input4>
```

Optionally I would like to control both the label column layouts widths and both the input elements widths.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you build a jsfiddle or codepen to play with for start. To achieve what you want, you'll need to wrap label and input in one container ie. `<li></li>` - does your requirement allow that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're asking, you mean that you just ant to use a "down-the-page" layout rather than "left-right-left-right"?

You can nest rows in order to keep the markup in the same order:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <label for="input-1" class="label-1 col-xs-6">Label 1</label>
                <input type="text" class="input-1 col-xs-6" />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="input-2" class="label-2 col-xs-6">Label 2</label>
                <input type="text" class="input-2 col-xs-6" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                <label for="input-3" class="label-3 col-xs-6">Label 3</label>
                <input type="text" class="input-3 col-xs-6" />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="input-4" class="label-4 col-xs-6">Label 4</label>
                <input type="text" class="input-4 col-xs-6" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/96pd1ung/

Comment: Cheers Tim, it's been a long day :)

Comment: No problem. That looks better :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, providing that you're able to manipulate markup, you could take advantage of `column-count` css property, to control number of columns your label/input items are split within. So, if you wrap your label/input pair in let's say list items:

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <label for="input1">label1</label>
            <input type="text" name="input1" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="input2">label2</label>
            <input type="text" name="input2" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="input3">label3</label>
            <input type="text" name="input3" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="input4">label4</label>
            <input type="text" name="input4" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

You can use this CSS:

```
ul {
    padding-left:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
}
li {

}
label, input {
    display:inline-block;
    width:49%;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle presenting this](http://jsfiddle.net/b748v299/1/).

[Browser support for Multiple-Column layout is shown here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn). Which is fairly good with vendor prefixes.

Hope this helps.